# Get feedback from query to webpage

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, post

So I have a div that I want to convert to a success alert after a successful insertion into the database. The AJAX success function of course runs only on successful POST to the PHP page, so how would I go about getting feedback from my insert query? Nothing shows up in my network tab that relates to the query.

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "follow.php",
                    data: {usrid: <?php echo "$sess_user_id1"; ?>, usrname: "<?php echo $sess_username; ?>", gender: <?php echo "$sess_gender"; ?>, markid: <?php echo "$markerid"; ?>, type: "<?php echo $type; ?>", usrhomelat: <?php echo "$sess_homelat"; ?>, usrhomelng: <?php echo "$sess_homelng"; ?>, blurb: ($("#textarea").val())},
                    success: function (data, msg) {
                        alert("Congratulations ");
                        $("#thanks").html(msg);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("At this time, you could not be added");
                    }
                });
```

Then on my follow.php page, I have my query, which, I know shouldn't be in mySQL(I will convert before taking the site live):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO markerfollowing (userID, username, gender, markerID, type, usrhomelat, usrhomelng, blurb)
            VALUES ('$user_id_follow', '$username2', '$gender', '$marker_id', '$type', '$usrhomelat', '$usrhomelng', '$blurb');";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

As you can probably tell, I am an amateur, so any assistance is greatly appreciated. I don't even know what search terms to use to address this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I can see your ajax call looks ok. Your problem lies in the data you are sending back and how you handle it.

If you do it in your way you just get a simple string. You could go for a call expecting json data like this.

Php part returns an array in json form.

```
$return = array();
if (!$result) {
    $return['success'] = 0;
    $return['message'] = 'Invalid query '.mysql_error();
} else {
    $return['success'] = 1;
    $return['message'] = 'Successfully saved!';
}

echo json_encode($return);
```

The ajax call changes like this (we'll be expecting a json object so we tell the ajax call what to expect from the server in dataType):

```
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
             if (data['success'] == 0) {
                 alert("Congratulations");
                 $("#thanks").html(data['message']);
             } else {
                 alert("At this time, you could not be added");
                 // You could also use the data['message'] that got sent back here.
             }
         }
```

The error function should not be used for transporting data from the follow.php script because it gets called if there was a more basic transfer type of error.

I hope that helps you with your problem.

Comment: Really can't thank you enough. Yes, it solved my problem, but more importantly I understand the process. Thank you SO much!